# rEFI and rEFInd both on boot

Tags: dual-boot, refit, refind

I'm trying to dual boot mac and linux. I installed rEFIt first than rEFInd,

I'm booting through two consecutive steps:

-rEFIt that proposes either mac or rEFInd

-rEFInd that proposes either mac or linux

I'd like to go only through rEFInd.

My mac's / directory shows no EFI files/directory

My linux's /boot directory is filed with old kernel version of EFI files (abi,config,memtest,initrd.img,vmlinuz etc..) that I'm not sure to know how to get rid of.

I tried autoremove with no success.

Thanks for your advices,

Raphael

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways to do this, although each has the potential to go awry:

### Method 1: From OS X

From OS X, you can use `bless` to set rEFInd as the default boot manager. This process is described in the rEFInd documentation:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx

Note that's the complete manual rEFInd installation process. You really only need steps 1, 2, and 8.

The problem with this approach is that, if your rEFIt installation includes rEFItBlesser (as it does by default), it may reset rEFIt as the default boot loader. You can work around this by removing `/Library/StartupItems/rEFItBlesser`. Alternatively, you can re-install rEFInd in OS X via the `refind-install` script, which should give you the option of removing rEFItBlesser.

### Method 2: From Ubuntu

In Ubuntu, typing `sudo efibootmgr -v` will produce a list of boot options. You can then use the `-o` option to `efibootmgr` to change the `BootOrder` line to set rEFInd as the first option. (For instance, you might type `sudo efibootmgr -o 0081,0080` to make `Boot0081` the default option, with `Boot0080` as a secondary boot option. The details of what values you type will vary from one system to another; that's why you start with `sudo efibootmgr -v` -- that shows you what options exist on *your* computer.) This will often work on Macs, but Macs are weird, and on some models it might fail. You may also run into the rEFItBlesser problem noted in the previous approach, so you may need to remove rEFItBlesser manually. (Note that re-installing rEFInd in Ubuntu won't remove rEFItBlesser in OS X.)

### Method 3: Delete rEFIt

You can completely delete rEFIt from the computer. It normally installs itself to `EFI/refit` in OS X, but depending on how you installed it, it may be somewhere else, such as on the ESP. (The ESP is normally not mounted in OS X, but may be mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu.) With rEFIt gone, the computer should boot to its second boot option, which may be rEFInd or OS X. If it starts booting straight to OS X, you'll need to re-install, or at least re-bless, rEFInd. There's a small chance that the computer will refuse to boot at all after you delete rEFIt. If so, holding down the Option key as you start up should produce the Mac's own built-in boot manager, which should enable you to get to OS X and recover.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for that very thorough answer.

For the record I went for option 3 got rid of every efi files I could find. As expected the refind boot went trash with the refit one.

I re-installed refind thanks to a live-usb img through linux directly to avoid the SIP issue.

Works like a charm.

Raphael